# Loop through many folders and do calculations with files with similar pattern in bash

Tags: bash, files, regular-expression

I have several folders each containing several `.nc` files. I want to loop through all folders and for each folder do some calculations (mergetime) using `cdo` on files that have similar pattern. So far I have written the following:

```
for dir in /mnt/meteo_a/africa_cordex/historical/0.44/pr/*/     
do 
 dir=${dir%*/}
 echo ${dir##*/} 
 export dir
 cd $dir
 pwd
  for f in `find . -type f -regex /(.*?\day)/*`
  cdo mergetiem io
  done
done
```

The files in each folder have names like the following:

```
pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19500101-19501231.nc
pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19510101-19551231.nc
pr_AFR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19491201-19501231.nc
pr_AFR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_day_19510101-19551231.nc
```

I want to apply the mergetime CDO command on all files that have similar pattern before `_day_`.

I want to merge the first two files and the last two files. More specifically, merge files that start with

```
"pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_"
```

and likewise merge files that start with

```
"pr_AFR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1"
```

The output of the mergetime can be something like:

```
 {pattern}_mergetime.nc
```

Comment: It is not clear which files you want to select with your `find` command. Please show a list of files with some matching and some non-matching files and state which ones you want to select or which files belong into the same group(s). What exactly means "similar pattern before `_day_`"?

Comment: I want to merge the first two files and the last two files. More specifically, merge files that start with "pr_AFR-44_CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5_historical_r1i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1_" and likewise merge files that start with "pr_AFR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r12i1p1_CLMcom-CCLM4-8-17_v1".

Comment: Please add the clarification to your question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: I had a quick look at the documentation of `cdo`, and I found out that the `mergetime` operator requires the name of the `outfile`. The required arguments are as follows: `cdo mergetime one_or_more_input_files one_outfile`. So, what or how do you want to name your output files?

Comment: It can be whatever is before "day" with a tag like: {pattern}_mergetime.nc

Comment: Again, you need to clarify that in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script snippet would work with your example files

```
for file in *.nc
do 
    echo "$file"
done | sed 's/_day_.*//' | sort -u | while read -r pattern
do
    cdo mergetime "${pattern}"* "${pattern}_mergetime.nc"
done
```

Explanation:

- The `for` loop with `echo` prints one file name per line.
- The `sed` command removes `_day_` and all following characters.
- `sort -u` sorts the partial file names and removes duplicates.
- `while read -r pattern` reads one pattern per line and loops over the patterns
- `"${pattern}"*` is expanded by the shell to all file names starting with the pattern

Better than the `for` loop with `echo` might be

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.nc'
```

This will print all file names matching `*.nc` in the current directory without subdirectories.

You can combine this with a loop over all subdirectories similar to the script in the question

```
for dir in /mnt/meteo_a/africa_cordex/historical/0.44/pr/*/     
do 
    dir=${dir%*/}
    echo ${dir##*/} 
    export dir
    pushd $dir
    pwd

    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.nc' | sed 's/_day_.*//' | sort -u | while read -r pattern
    do
        cdo mergetime "${pattern}"* "${pattern}_mergetime.nc"
    done

    popd
done
```

Instead of `cd` I propose `pushd` to allow going back with `popd` later.

You could also replace the `for` loop over the directories with an additional `find`

```
find /mnt/meteo_a/africa_cordex/historical/0.44/pr -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir
do
    pushd "$dir"

    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.nc' | sed 's/_day_.*//' | sort -u | while read -r pattern
    do
        cdo mergetime "${pattern}"* "${pattern}_mergetime.nc"
    done

    popd
done
```

Comment: @MariaKarypidou If it works you can accept the answer. I read in a comment that the `cdo` command needs an output file argument. I will add this to my answer.